# MongoDB issue at deployment

Tags: java, mongodb

I am fairly new to MongoDB: my app running on my mac does not deploy well on ubuntu.

I have a very basic program that takes a JSon file and dumps it in a MongoDB db. The MongoDB db is on a remote Ubuntu server called `db`.

The program works fine on my Mac, in Eclipse and command line.

When I deploy it on my Ubuntu-based app server (different than the db server), I get:

```
[cluster-ClusterId{value='572387cf96720e25144dce5b', description='null'}-db:27017] INFO org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server db:27017
com.mongodb.MongoInterruptedException: Interrupted acquiring a permit to retrieve an item from the pool
```

The app server can ping the db server.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* it is because my app is trying to save a `null` object as a Document...